# How do I make a different messagebox show up depending on the answer from a previous one? Python

Tags: python, messagebox

This may seem like a simple problem but I can't figure it out because I just started learning Python.
I want to make a messagebox with a Yes and No answer t a question which I did do, but I want another messagebox to show up depending on whether you click Yes or No.

I first made the question itself which worked out:

```
messagebox.askquestion('Question', 'Do you wish to engage in combat?')
```

Here is what it looked like:

[image: Here is what it looked like]

I wanted to add a showinfo box that will show up either way but will vary depending on the button I click, for example, when you click Yes, it will close the current popup but open a showinfo box saying ":)", ":(" for when I click No. I can't figure out how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which package you're using.

Usually, when you click the button(either yes or no), it will be returned, so you gonna have a variable to store the result.

With the answer, you can make the decision of popping a new info box or any other behavior.

e.g.

```
flag = messagebox.askquestion('Question', 'Do you wish to engage in combat?')
if flag == "yes"
    pop :)
else:
    pop :(
```

or

```
question = messagebox.askquestion('Question', 'Do you wish to engage in combat?')
if question.status == "yes":
    pop :)
else:
    pop :(
```

The method of popping boxes of other types should also depend on what package you are using.

-------------------Updates----------------------

So this is the example

```
from tkinter.messagebox import askquestion, showinfo
result = askquestion("Question", "Do you love me?")

if result == "yes":
    showinfo(message=":)")
else:
    showinfo(message=":(")
```

or you could use `askyesno` instead of `askquestion`, which will return a boolean type `True` or `Flase`
e.g.

```
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno, showinfo
result = askyesno("Question", "Do you love me?")
if result:
    showinfo(message=":)")
else:
    showinfo(message=":(")
```

Comment: If I use either one, it gives me an "invalid syntax" for ":)"
im using messagebox from tkinter

Comment: Oh... the ':)' just fake codes, I meant that you could implement the logic there.
I will update the answer with examples